# How do I free disk space allocated to virtual box after uninstallint it?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, disk

I had allocated a disk space of 35GB to virtualbox and now even after uninstalling it, the allocated disk space is not freed.

Comment: As far as  I know the allocated space  just makes the "hdd" file the full size of the VM you created .. If you deleted the VM you may have chose to save the files .. if so you need to go to the VM folder and delete the 35GB vbox file/files for the VM

Comment: I am unable to find any VM folder in my system but I'm searching for ".vdi" files using **find . -type f -name "*.vdi"** command but it says permission denied
**find: `./.cache/dconf': Permission denied**
**find: `./.gvfs': Permission denied**

Answer (score 1):

If you have removed the Virtual Box application you need to manually delete the .vdi files that are stored in the location you defined in Preferences -> General -> Default Machine Folder either with your file manager or from the command line

Comment: I tried to find .vdi files from the terminal using the command 

find . -type f -name "*.vdi"  
but it shows Permission denied

find: `./.cache/dconf': Permission denied
find: `./.gvfs': Permission denied

Comment: Run your find command elevated, so sudo find etc etc. Also, by default your VM directory is in your home folder, did you change this ?

Comment: try sudo su and enter your password and run as root.